# Page Bean not saved in FlowScope Jsf 2.2

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, websphere-8, flow-scope

While i create a application my page bean not saved in @FlowScoped . by default stored in Request scope here my code :

```
enter code here 
package com.webage.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.flow.FlowScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="flow1")
@FlowScoped(value = "flow1")
public class Flow1Bean implements Serializable {

    public String cusName;
    public String city;
    public String getName() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    }

    public String doReturnValue() {

        return "return1";
    }

    /**
     * @return the cusName
     */
    public String getCusName() {
        return cusName;
    }

    /**
     * @param cusName the cusName to set
     */
    public void setCusName(String cusName) {
        this.cusName = cusName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the city
     */
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * @param city the city to set
     */
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
}
```

My Xhtml file here i'm getting input from page and store it in page bean.:

```
<p>
            <span id="param1FromFlow1">Flow bean
                param1Value:<h:inputText id="input"
                    value="#{flow1.cusName}" /> </span>
        </p>

        <h:outputText value="#{null != facesContext.application.flowHandler.currentFlow}" >
        </h:outputText>

        <p></p>
        <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Next" styleClass="commandButton"
            id="button1" action="flow1a"></h:commandButton>
        <p></p>
```

The below code return "false" in flow/flow1.xhtml file

```
<h:outputText value="#{null != facesContext.application.flowHandler.currentFlow}" >
        </h:outputText>
```

Answer (score 1):

Flowscope is a CDI scope. Use `@Named` instead of `@ManagedBean`.